# Laravel - function according to form parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I am giving the option to the user to decide if he wants to delete his account or not, and I can't seem to find a way to run (or not) the function to delete the account according to his choice... here is the code:

firstly I thought of adding to ProfileController something like `if $form['confirm'] = 'yes', run function` but it didn't work...

**web.php**

```
Route::get('delete_account/{id}', 'ProfileController@deleteProfile');
Route::post('deleteAccount', 'ProfileController@delete')->name('deleteAccount');
```

**HTML (pages.delete_account)**

```
<div class="big">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('deleteAccount') }}">
        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
        <input id="yes" type="radio" name="confirm" value="{{ old('yes') }}" required autofocus>
        <label for="no">No</label>
        <input id="no" type="radio" name="confirm" value="{{ old('no') }}" required autofocus>
        <button type="deleteAccount">
            Confirm
        </button>
</div>
```

**ProfileController.php**

```
    public function deleteProfile($id)
    {
      if (!Auth::check()) return redirect('/login');

      return view('pages.delete_account');
    }

    public function delete(Request $request)
    {
      $user = Events::find(Auth::user()->id);

      $this->authorize('delete', $user);
      $user->delete();

      return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Are there any other parts of the code you need to fully understand the question? Please let me know :)

Comment: May i ask. Why are you giving the user a yes/no option and why not simply display a button with text "Confirm Deletion" and if the user clicks it you can delete directly?

Comment: that's a great question... it would require javascript, right?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. You just send the form as you're doing now but with just a button. I will add an answer down.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve deletion of the user without asking for confirmation via radio button or something directly by just having a confirmation button.

```
<div class="big">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('deleteAccount') }}">
        <button type="submit">
            Confirm Deletion
        </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what I was saying is, i currently have a little button with a bin which when you click, it sends you to the other page with the POST method. This confirmation button of yours would need to be invisible at first and then, after clicking the bin button, this would appear to confirm. Does it make sense?